# EWS Java obtaining appointment attendee meeting response

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I've seen some c# code to get this done, but not sure what the equivalent is in Java.  That said....

I've been iterating through all the available conference rooms and then gathering their appointments and trying to get stats about them.  Have everything now but the actual meeting response, I specifically load the attendees, what do I have to do to get the attendee response?  All responses are 'unknown' currently.

```
FindItemsResults<Appointment> aps = service.findAppointments(folderid, new CalendarView(startDate1,endDate1));
for (Item items : aps.getItems())
{
    PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject);
    ps.add(AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees);
    ps.add(AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees);
    ps.add(AppointmentSchema.Resources);
    ps.add(AppointmentSchema.MyResponseType);
    items.load(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
    Appointment appt = (Appointment)items;

    System.out.println("Required Attendees========"+appt.getRequiredAttendees().getCount());                    
    System.out.println("Resource Count========"+appt.getResources().getCount());
    System.out.println("Optional Attendees========"+appt.getOptionalAttendees().getCount());
    int accepted=0;
    AttendeeCollection RA=appt.getRequiredAttendees();
    for (int i=0; i<appt.getRequiredAttendees().getCount(); i++){
        System.out.println(RA.getPropertyAtIndex(i).getResponseType().equals(MeetingResponseType.Accept));
        System.out.println(RA.getPropertyAtIndex(i).getName());

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RA.getPropertyAtIndex(i).getResponseType().toString()
should get you what you are looking for.

I noticed that in Outlook, while responding to meeting invite you have to "Respond without/with Comments"

Answer (score 0):

You can only obtain attendee responses by querying the organizer's calendar. So

1. Make sure you have the needed permissions
2. Use the folder ID of the organizer's calendar

   ```
   FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("organizer@company.com"))
   ```

For more references see
[Tracking meeting responses by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633669(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the extended property: [PidLidResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidresponsestatus-canonical-property).

In XML it is described as:

```
<m:GetItem>
  <m:ItemShape>
    <t:AdditionalProperties>
      <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertyId="33304" PropertyType="Integer" />
```

Note that in the documentation it is an integer, but I found that it returns a string on some servers.